# Checkbox validation in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-checkbox

I am developing an Android application where I have a screen with check boxes and a button (generated programmatically). I want to allow at most three check boxes to be checked when a user clicks on the button.

I was hoping that there would be something like a check box group in Android, but unfortunately there isn't.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this..

```
     chkIos = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkIos);
            chkAndroid = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkAndroid);
            chkWindows = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkWindows);
            btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

            btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                  //Run when button is clicked
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                 if(chkIos.isChecked() || chkAndroid.isChecked() || chkWindows.isChecked()){
                 //do some validation
                 }
              }
            }); 
          }
```

**Edit:-**
Yes, but if added dynamically you atleast got to have number count of checkboxes, say

```
CheckBox[] check = new CheckBox[maxCount];
```

inside your button click

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
                // for(int i = 0; i < check.length; i++){
if(check[1].isChecked() || .... ){
     //your validation here..
     }
}
```

Comment: But here you have assumed that there are going to be 2 checkboxes. In my application I cannot know from before the number of checkboxes.

Comment: @Newbie Edited the post plz check

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know I could create array do check boxes like that. Thnx !

Comment: Happy to help, if that solves your problem, you can upVote and mark this answer as solved for others to benifit...

Answer (score 0):

Just do it manually, increment some counter in the onCheckedChanged, its trivial work.